# Oracle : impdp ORA-39001: invalid argument value

Tags: oracle

I want to import a dmp file I have it in this path:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\pr\projects\db\test.dmp
```

I created a directory like this :

```
SQL> create directory testdir as 'C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\pr\projects\db';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory testdir to c##stage;

Grant succeeded.
```

When I run the following command

```
impdp c##stage/stage SCHEMAS=stage DIRECTORY=testdir DUMPFILE=test.DMP EXCLUDE=CONSTRAINT,REF_CONSTRAINT,INDEX TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE nologfile=y
```

I got this errors

```
Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-31640: unable to open dump file "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\pr\projects\db\test.DMP" for read
ORA-27041: unable to open file
OSD-04002: ouverture impossible du fichier
O/S-Error: (OS 5) Acc┐refus┐
```

notes:
I don't know if the exporter used `exp` or `expdp` to export file.

Comment: The account the database service is running under needs to be able to see the directory, not just you; so having the file on your own desktop isn't likely to work. Can you move it to a shared area, e.g. c:\temp, and redefine the directory object to point to that instead?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you so much. I did what you suggested and the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

What is the c##?

Try narrowing it down by setting

CONTENT=DATA_ONLY

If you are doing content=data_only, then all of the metadata is excluded by default so you don't need any of these:

EXCLUDE=REF_CONSTRAINT

EXCLUDE=CONSTRAINT

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is solved thanks to @AlexPoole's comment.